# Getting error in Gatling -> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nextgen.SetUpApplyFlowAndLottery

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I am trying to upgrade from Gatling 3.5 to 3.7. I think I already did it

My steps to do the upgrade:

1- Changed some values in the pom.xml
2- Ran the command → mvn clean install

I did not get any error and my pom.xml now looks like:

[image]

I am running the following command to run a Gatling script that was working in version 3.5:

[image]

but now I get the following error

[image]

For privacy policies in my company i cannot share the fully script but this is the beginning

[image]

Why am i getting this error ? did i do something wrong in the upgrade ? do i have to add something else in the pom.xml file ? do i have to check something else ?

Again, i did not touch the script and it was working in version 3.5

Comment: Answered on Gatling forum: https://community.gatling.io/t/getting-the-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-nextgen-setupapplyflowandlottery/6631/3